# HybridAuth redirect loop with Yii in facebook authentication

Tags: php, yii, hybridauth

I know there are many questions regarding this issue and because they didn't help me I'm asking new one.

Let me tell you how I've been trying to integrate. I've two actions in my controller **actionIndex** and **actionDone** .

In the first action I try to authenticate user (if the is already authenticated I grab user information and save it into my database) and in the second action I just include hybrid index.php (to process hybridauth).

And the most interesting thing I'm going to tell is that **This work perfectly on localhost** but not in **live server**

It is really annoying and wasted many hours.
here is code of both actions:

```
$ha = $this->_getHA(); //i'm just bring files here
$adapter = $ha->authenticate('facebook');

if ($adapter->isUserConnected()) {

  // get user profile
  $profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

  /*
   * If user has authenticated already
   */
  $social_id = (int) $profile->identifier;

  ....
  }
}
```

Second Action:

```
 public function actionDone() {

  $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias("ext.hybridauth.index") . '.php';
  require $path;


}
```

**Note:** I'am sure my base_url is correct.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Many faces this program due to circular login. What I mean is You have method M that need login and then it redirects to login. But somehow (due to access limit) login method itself requires user be login so it redirects itself ad infinitum. Check if that is not the issue. I'm not conversant with HA so can't help here!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the Same problem many times . Your Server base-path not configured correctly . You just check  this variable

```
   $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias("ext.hybridauth.index") . '.php';
```

try to change by this way it may help

```
 $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias("ext.hybridauth") .'/index.php';
```

Comment: try to print the $path variable before you check

Comment: thanks for the answer, no my approach is as true as yours. BTW I tested but nothing happened,

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers you can then get the Hybrid_Auth object:

```
$ha = Yii::app()->getModule('hybridauth')->getHybridAuth();
$facebook = $ha->getAdapter('facebook');
$facebook->setUserStatus('Hi');
```

[use this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/#hh2)